# How do I fix the error "deviceInputWithDevice is unavailable"?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm "upgrading" my app from Swift to Swift 2 and came across the follow error:
`'deviceInputWithDevice' is unavailable: use object construction 'AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:error:)'`

Here is the code in question:

```
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    var input:AVCaptureDeviceInput
    let error:NSError?

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

Can someone help me understand the suggested solution: "use object construction 'AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:error:)'" and how I can implement it please?

Answer (score 18):

```
    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        // moved the rest of the image capture into the do{} scope.
```

Comment: found it ```catch let error as NSError {
    println(error) }```